# Cannot input Vietnamese(Unikey)!

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, ibus, input-method

So here's the problem. I just installed **Kubuntu 16.04 amd64** on my laptop. It just seems I can't input Vietnamese into any application although I've installed ibus-unikey, started it's daemon, configured the settings of iBus.

I went to the terminal to check I had everything needed(ibus-qt4...etc) but it doesn't seem to be anything missing.

I have Also tried fcitx-unikey. Doesn't work too!

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation I can think of is that you haven't configured the input methods.

- Open the *Input Method* tool from the menus (or launch it from a terminal window with the `im-config` command).
- Select IBus (for ibus-unikey) or Fcitx (for fcitx-unikey).
- Reboot.

This will start the applicable input method framework (IBus or Fcitx) automatically, and also set the necessary environment variables.

Comment: I ran it. When the dialog come up aking me do I want to update the configuration I clicked yes. Then nothing happened!

Comment: oh wait. I fixed it. Did exactly the same as you said and im done! Thanks again!

Comment: @DrunkenMaster: This question was about Kubuntu. Please ask a new question if you have problems with Vietnamese on Ubuntu.